# How do hierarchical XSL sorting?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, treeview, hierarchy

I have the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soldiers>
    <soldier>
        <name>John</name>
        <supervisor>Marcus</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>Marcus</name>
        <supervisor>Mike</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>Frank</name>
        <supervisor>Marcus</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <supervisor>Anna</supervisor>
    </soldier>
</soldiers>
```

Now I'm looking for a way sorting this XML hierarchicaly  based  on supervisor tag. What's the most performant way to do this? The result of the given example should look as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soldiers>
    <soldier>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <supervisor>Anna</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>Marcus</name>
        <supervisor>Mike</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>John</name>
        <supervisor>Marcus</supervisor>
    </soldier>
    <soldier>
        <name>Frank</name>
        <supervisor>Marcus</supervisor>
    </soldier>
</soldiers>
```

So Mike has no supervisor listed in here, hence he is on the top. Marcus' supervisor is Mike, hence he is under Mike. John's and Frank's supervisor is Marcus, hence they are at the very bottom.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it supoorts XSLT 1.0

Comment: Not a good answer. Please read the question again.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes it supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Do you want to list subordinates under their superiors (as provided by Martin Honnen's answer), or do you want to list the soldiers sorted by their superiority? Your example is ambiguous in this aspect. If you had another soldier whose superior is Anna, where should it appear?

Comment: In the scenario you describe it wouldn't matter where the new soldier would be placed, until he is a supervisor of some soldier. It is crucial for me to process the supervisors in hierarchical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `key` to follow the references:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="soldier" use="supervisor"/>

    <xsl:template match="soldiers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="soldier[not(supervisor = ../soldier/name)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soldier">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', name)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Based on the comment of @michael.hor257k you might rather want

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="mf">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="soldier" use="supervisor"/>

    <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:refs" as="element(soldier)*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="element(soldier)*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$input"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="if (key('ref', $input/name, $main-root)) then mf:refs(key('ref', $input/name, $main-root)) else ()"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="soldiers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:refs(soldier[not(supervisor = ../soldier/name)])"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

which uses the same key but outputs each level completely first before recursing to the next level.